# Develop same app for Android and iOS using React or Flutter

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-studio, flutter

I just finished my Android app.
Sadly, people who are using iOS are asking me for app development in iOS.

I made my app with Android Studio.
Now I'm looking at cross platform like Flutter and React.

Now I just can't build the project from Android Studio to get an iOS app binary, so is there a way to import the Android Studio project and use it in React/Flutter?

What should I use React or Flutter?

I'm just trying not to spend months! :)

EDIT: I forgot to say that my app is made of a MapsActivity and some static activities so I hope it will be not so hard to migrate to Flutter or React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no solutions available for transforming android application into a flutter or react native or any other framework.
Both React Native and Flutter are great in building cross-platform applications, but flutter got a slight edge in terms of elegant UI. If you want to build beautiful UI quickly, then definitely go for Flutter. There are some other benefits with Flutter like with the same code base, you can create an application for Desktop(Windows + Linux + Mac) and Web also.
Also, Flutter provides better performance than React Native because Flutter uses skia engine that doesn't require a bridge for communicating with the native components. On the other hand, React Native requires a JavaScript bridge for communicating with the native components.
Setting up CI/CD for Flutter apps is easy than React Native.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there are **no reliable converters** or elegant hacks to transform an Android App into another framework.

Meaning, you will have to program the same app, all over again :(

When, choosing between React Native and Flutter, there are pros and cons as with anything, but I believe it can be basically boiled down to the points highlighted in this [article](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-what-to-choose-in-2021#f27).

Basically:

- Flutter uses Dart which is only used in Flutter, vs. Javascript being used in React Native and many parts of web development.
- Styling is harder in React Native, easier in Flutter
- Flutter has better performance overall, but considering really big apps have been developed using React Native(Instagram, Uber Eats, Discord), it's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there is no converted out there which can lets you convert your app into another framework.

But if you are asking what to choose I will suggest going with Flutter, as you are familiar with OOP with Java/Kotlin and designing UI will be a lot easier in flutter, you might struggle with declarative pattern but once you learn it, it will be lot easier, also if you have mac you can try tools like [Supernova](https://www.supernova.io/) and [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/in/products/xd.html)